# Which is more efficient Cstr(value) or value.ToString()

Tags: vb.net, casting

I am wondering which is more efficient, using `CStr()` or `object.toString()`.
The reason I ask this is because I thought all that CStr() does is to invoke the .ToString() method on the object it was dealing with.

But when recently using a generic method without any type constraints I had to use object.ToString() instead of CStr(object).

The following is purely an example to illustrate the issue.

```
Public Function IDFromObject(Of ID_TYPE)(ByVal value As ID_TYPE) As String
    Return value.ToString
End Function
```

Compiled as expected, but the following did not using CStr(). It gave an compilation error value of type ID_TYPE cannot be converted to string. But it obviously can use .ToString()

```
Public Function IDFromObject(Of ID_TYPE)(ByVal value As ID_TYPE) As String
    Return CStr(value)
End Function
```

Comment: Make sure when you test this that you compile it for RELEASE with optimizations.  If you run this in debug, especially in the IDE, the results will be completely different.

Comment: Note that (A) CStr(x) works for nulls but x.ToString() will fail, and (B) Enums are different; CStr(e) returns "2" but e.ToString() returns "LeftToRight"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [here](http://www.techtalkz.com/vb-net/130907-cstr-vs-tostring-best-use.html) (couldn't say it any better):

> CStr is a keyword, whereas ToString is
>   a function (method). CStr is compiled
>   inline and it creates code depending
>   on the type of the passed object. It's
>   mainly there for people being used to
>   it from previous VB versions. I
>   haven't used CStr in .Net anymore
>   (because it's not obvious what it does
>   in which situations and it's also not
>   very well documented).
>
> The difference depends on which
>   ToString function you use. Every type
>   can have it's own implementation.

Answer (score 8):

For readability sake, if I were in the need to write code in VB.NET (I am a C# programmer), I would avoid the VB specific keywords/functions as much as possible. By using .NET classes and methods only, your code will be more understandable by people used to develop in other .NET languages. Not to mention that these functions are there mainly for compatibility with VB6 and they look a bit out of place compared to the .NET way of doing things.

Of course there may be reasonable exceptions, sometimes VB.NET really makes very easy to do certain tasks and it can be convenient to take advantage of this; but as a genereal rule I would not use any VB.NET specific function.

Comment: May I ask how to know a keyword or function is VB specific or belongs to .NET?

Comment: Oh. I got it. In Mirosoft Docs, CStr is under Visual Basic while ToString is under .NET.

Answer (score 6):

One BIG difference between CStr as ToString is handling of Enum variables.

CStr returns the underlying number e.g. "2" and ToString returns the Enum name e.g. "LeftToRight"

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but no one else bothered to check or cite the Visual Basic documentation, and it recommends the opposite of what most of these answers do. This is straight from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions#remarks):

> As a rule, you should use the Visual Basic type conversion functions in preference to the .NET Framework methods such as ToString(), either on the Convert class or on an individual type structure or class. The Visual Basic functions are designed for optimal interaction with Visual Basic code, and they also make your source code shorter and easier to read.

That said, **sometimes there *are* differences between what `CStr` and `ToString` will return, so performance and readability aren't the only considerations**. There is an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14013356/2299915) on another question that describes when and why this is the case. Reproduced here:

> The ToString method is a standard public method that returns a String. It is a method that is defined by the base Object type as overrideable. Each class can, therefore, override that method to return anything that it wants. It is quite common for classes to override the ToString method to make it return a nice human-readable description of the object.
>
> CStr, on the other hand, is a casting operator. It is shorthand for CType(x, String). The casting operator, like many other operators, can be overridden by any class. Normally, though, you want casting operations to return the closest representation of the actual value of the original object, rather than a descriptive string.
>
> It is not unusual then, that you may want ToString to return a different result than CStr. In the case of an enum, each member is essentially an Integer, so CStr on an enum member works the same as CStr on an integer. That is what you would expect. However, ToString has been overridden to return the more human readable version of the value. That is also what you would expect.

## So, in summary:

When you want the closest string representation of the actual value of the original object, you should use `CStr()`. When you want the (potentially) customized, human-readable version of the value, you should use `.ToString`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code from the above test, but redone with System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch, and removing the Console.write bottleneck.

It turns out directcasting is fastest(as well it should be - it isn't doing anything in this case. However its a trivialised example because its rare you would want to convert a string to a string. Converting 
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

```
    Dim obj As Object = "asdfsdasdfsadfasdfasdfasdfsdasdfsadfasdfasdfdafsdfasd"
    Dim LL As New List(Of String), SWW As System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch

    LL.Clear()

    SWW = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
        LL.Add(obj.ToString)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("obj.ToString took {0}.", SWW.ElapsedTicks)

    LL.Clear()
    SWW = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
        LL.Add(CStr(obj))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("CStr(obj) took {0}.", SWW.ElapsedTicks)

    LL.Clear()
    SWW = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
        LL.Add(DirectCast(obj, String))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("DirectCast(obj, String) took {0}.", SWW.ElapsedTicks)





    Console.WriteLine("---------------- Integer To String ----------- ")

    obj = 15522

    LL.Clear()
    SWW = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
        LL.Add(obj.ToString)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("obj.ToString took {0}.", SWW.ElapsedTicks)

    LL.Clear()
    SWW = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
        LL.Add(CStr(obj))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("CStr(obj) took {0}.", SWW.ElapsedTicks)

    LL.Clear()
    SWW = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
        Dim str As String = TryCast(obj, String)
        ' This obviously fails, as obj is not a string, which is why it is so fast.. str is then nothing
        LL.Add(str)

    Next
    Console.WriteLine("DirectCast(obj, String) took {0}.", SWW.ElapsedTicks)

    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

End Module

My results:

`(string ) : ToString : 2288;  CStr: 2275; DirectCast: 1586`

`(integer) : ToString : 10526; CStr: 13184; TryCast: 982`

Comment: This is not a fair test for .ToString( ), as List() initial capacity should be set to Short.MaxValue.  The first run resizes the List several times, then the next two tests run a little faster.  If you set the initial capacity, you'll find .ToString( ) is faster than CStr( ), but not quite as fast as directcast.

Answer (score 1):

They are two completely different things, CStr is an overloaded function that converts the data within certain types into a string while ToString calls a method that all .net objects have and which you can override but which by default contains the name of the object. ToString will only return the data of a type if it has been overridden to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the results of a little test I made:

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()

    Dim obj As Object = "asdfsdasdfsadfasdfasdfasdfsdasdfsadfasdfasdfdafsdfasd"
    Dim y = Now, z = Now

    y = Now
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
      Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString)
    Next
    z = Now
    Dim time1 = z - y

    y = Now
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
      Console.WriteLine(CStr(obj))
    Next
    z = Now

    Dim time2 = z - y
    y = Now
    For i = 0 To Short.MaxValue
      Console.WriteLine(DirectCast(obj, String))
    Next
    z = Now

    Dim time3 = z - y

    Console.WriteLine("obj.ToString took {0}.", time1)
    Console.WriteLine("CStr(obj) took {0}.", time2)
    Console.WriteLine("DirectCast(obj, String) took {0}.", time3)
    Console.Read()
  End Sub
End Module
```

**Results:**

```
obj.ToString() took 00:00:06.9303964.
CStr(obj) took 00:00:06.8763933.
DirectCast(obj, String) took 00:00:06.8903941.
```

Which makes it certain that `CStr` is the fastest, then goes `DirectCast` and finally `ToString` with highes performance cost.

Comment: Most of your time is taken by the console.write method... I have rewritten your test below, and it actually turns out directcast is fastest in this particular instance, by nearly double.

Comment: The above difference is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to time the following two subroutines (forgive my variable naming):

```
 For i As Integer = 1 To 1000
        For j As Integer = 1 To 65536
            eee = aaa.ToString()
            eee = bbb.ToString()
            eee = ccc.ToString()
            eee = ddd.ToString()
            eee = Nothing
        Next
 Next
```

and

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 1000
        For j As Integer = 1 To 65536
            eee = CStr(aaa)
            eee = CStr(bbb)
            eee = CStr(ccc)
            eee = CStr(ddd)
            eee = Nothing
        Next
    Next
```

where

```
    Dim aaa As Integer = 1233
    Dim bbb As Single = 445.234234234
    Dim ccc As Double = 234234.234457634
    Dim ddd As Decimal = 1231.3466734523424
    Dim eee As String = Nothing
```

the `ToString()` loop takes 62 seconds and the `CStr()` loop takes 64 seconds. It is really not a huge impact in my opinion, if you are only dealing with numbers. I disabled any compiler optimization during the timing process.

Answer (score -1):

CStr(object) is a cast (equivalent to (string)object in C#) and will throw esxception if given a null obejct or an object that cannot be casted to string. However .ToString() will work on any type of object (since it implemented in the Object class) and if not overridden by the current class will return the base ToString() method. In your case you must override ToString() method in your ID_TYPE class and return the string you need.

Comment: Obviously, calling ToString() on a null object will not work. So in that respect, it is the same as CStr :)

Comment: CStr(Nothing) returns Nothing, it does not throw an exception, whereas Nothig.ToString throws an exception.