# CStr() vs. Str() vs. .ToString()

Tags: vb.net, string

I want to know what exactly are the differences between `CStr()`, `Str()` and `.ToString()`?

```
Label1.Text = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 10))
```

and

```
Label1.Text = Str(Int(Rnd() * 10))
```

and

```
Label1.Text = Int(Rnd() * 10).ToString
```

If I use this condition:

```
If Label1.Text = "7" Then
     'Some code here
End If
```

`Str()` doesn't work here. What's the difference?

Comment: What in the documentation of these do you not understand?

Comment: @Oded, why the **Str()** did not work n my code?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979880

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**ToString** will call the `.ToString()` function on a particular instance.
In practice, this means that it will throw an exception if the object in
question is `Nothing`. However, you can implement `.ToString()` in your own
classes to get a useful string representation of your object, whereas
`CType`/`CStr` only work with built-in classes and interfaces.

**CStr** and **CType(*expression*, String)** are exactly equivalent (I'm not
sure where the other poster got the idea that `CStr` is faster). But they
aren't really functions, they're compiler directives that will emit very
different code depending on the declaration of *expression*. In most
cases, these directives call a bunch of internal VB code that tries to
get a reasonable string out of *expression*.

**DirectCast(*expression*, String)** assumes that the expression in
question really is a `String` and just casts it. It's the fastest of all
these options, but will throw an exception if *expression* is anything
other than a `String`.

Comment: How do people do that? How do you answer a question so quickly and so comprehensively? :-p

Comment: +1: You could add that `Str` is a throw back to the very earliest versions of Basic. `Str` converts a number to a string. If the number is positive it puts in a leading space. If the number is negative there is no leading space but there is a minus sign, therefore `Str(10)` & `Str(-10)` will both produce strings 3 characters in length. I'd recommend using the `ToString()` method on primitives, they're  far more powerful, with many more options.

Comment: +1 But there are also important differences regarding **internationalisation**. `CStr` and `ToString` take account of culture settings, so for instance might use comma as decimal separator when converting numbers to strings, will use localised month names when converting dates, and so on. `Str` is invariant and always uses US settings: dot for decimal separator and so on. There are overloads of `ToString` which allow you to specify the format or the locale to use.

Comment: Cstr/CType, both call  Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString, which has a bunch of overloads.  How those overloads differ from using .ToString on the base type values isn't documented anywhere that I could find.

Answer (score 4):

As an Addition to the VBA/VB6 Environment where we have no `ToString()`:

- `Str()` **is not aware** of international representation. The decimal separator always is a dot (`.`).

  As already mentioned above it prefixes the resulting string with a blank in case of positive values.
- There also exists `Str$()`. The difference to `Str()` is the return type:

  `Str()` returns a variant of type string, `Str$()` returns a string.

  And `Str$()` is slightly faster then `Str()`.
- `CStr()` in contrast **is aware** of international representation. The decimal separator depends on the Windows international settings.

  No additional prefixing for positive values will be done.

So if you need to convert a value type to a string and have to **ensure a dot as a decimal separator and no prefixing blank**, then use this syntax:

```
Dim d As Double
d = 123.456

Dim s As String
s = Trim(Str$(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know about ToString() and i don't know about VB.NET**

**But in VB6 (Visual Basic 6):**

Both of Cstr() and Str() converts values to string. but Cstr() is better because:

**Str():** After converting to string it adds 1 space before positive numbers. for example: Str(22) > " 22"

**Cstr():** After converting to string it never adds the above extra space - For best result use it with Trim() - Trim(Cstr(Variable))

Comment: Why would I need to `Trim()` the result of `Cstr()` if it never adds an extra space?

Comment: @JeffBridgman because i'm pernickety :D i can't see inside of the cstr() and i don't trust it 100%... but i'm sure the trim() removes all the spaces around the string or the number that converted to string :D

Comment: CStr never adds a space. No need to trim.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a problem in the code in the question, it is important to mention that `Str()` only converts numerical expressions to string, gives an error in other cases, so don't use it for converting values of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is `str()` is evil as it always prepends a space for the sign character so if you are comparing values it fails. Instead use `CStr()` instead which does not do this.

You may comes across business logic that tries to do this:

Eg:

```
Dim sVar as String = "1"
Dim i as Integer = 1
console.write( cstr(i) = sVar )
```

Which outputs:

```
False
```

I lost a couple hours on this one as the code was quite deep in old code and was very difficult to grok in production environment where logging based debugging was all that was available.