# CStr() vs Str()

Tags: vb6

I have to modify some old VB6 code, but I've been using VB.Net for so long I have forgotten some of the subtleties, and documentation is getting harder to find.

In Vb.Net CStr() takes into account international settings and uses commas instead of dots for people with foreign language settings whereas Str() always uses English conventions. I can't remember though if this was the same in VB6.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46815283/5162073) is a similar question.

Comment: Thanks. I did see that question, but that was a question about Vb.Net. One of the answers does suggest that CStr() uses international settings, but it is not absolutely clear that they are specifically referring to VB6 in that part of the answer. This issue was not the focus of that question.

Comment: But the answer I linked was specific to VB6.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) is a link to a Microsoft page.

Comment: Here is a blurb from my MSDN Library on the page showing CStr - "You should use the data-type conversion functions instead of Val to provide internationally aware conversions from one data type to another.".

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is a VBA not a VB6 documentation reference although I am sure it is the same.

Comment: `Str` and `Val` are locale invariant while `CStr` and `CDbl` use locale settings for the conversions. One should use `Str` and `Val` in a JSON parser implementation for instance.

Comment: @PhilPreen VB6 hosts the VBA language just as Office does. All VB6 language keywords are ONLY in VBA's help. Try it - put text caret over `str` and press F1 and you will get the VBA help. VB6's help is the forms package (as VB6 and Office have different forms packages), the clipboard object, and Printer object.

Comment: No, VB6 does not host VBA as Office does.  It is amazing how much people "know" that just ain't so.  And every legal copy of the VB6 developer tools includes the documentation.  Are you using a pirated copy?  The VBA scripting language is a subset of VB, much as VBScript is.  As such there is some common documentation.

Comment: Bob77 I agree. VB6 did not 'host VBA' as Office does. The two languages are pretty much identical. Whether there was any shared code in the interpreter at that time I have no idea.

Comment: Bob77. I do not have any original disks but am able to use VB6 through my company's MSDN subscription. It is available for download as iso images. At the time of posting this question, I had not yet installed the VB6 IDE nor MSDN (the help system) but was able to make simple code changes using Windows NotePad.

Answer (score 2):

OK,  tested it by changing my locale settings, and the following code..

Yes it seems that CSTR() is locale aware, and STR() isnt..

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim X As String
    Dim Z As Currency
    Z = 456789.12
    X = CStr(Z) 'with locale settings of sep='.' and dec=',' prints 456789,12
    'X = Str(Z) 'with locale settings of sep='.' and dec=',' prints 456789.12
    Me.Caption = X
End Sub
```