# OPTION STRICT OFF - NULL Exception

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Dim strHideReason As String = strHideReason & " " & objDBDR.GetName(intHideCheck) & " is " & objDBDR(intHideCheck)
```

objDBDR(intHideCheck) is null.  objDBDR is a datareader.

The code above compiles, however I am trying to set option strict to on, so I now have to do this:

```
Dim strHideReason As String = strHideReason & " " & objDBDR.GetName(intHideCheck) & " is " & cstr(objDBDR(intHideCheck))
```

It now throws an exception.  I can refactor the code to resolve this, however I am confused why the first compiles.  Does the compiler ignore objects that are null in string concatenations when option strict is off?

Comment: the NullReference will be thrown whether OPTION STRICT is on or not.  The warning to convert `objDBDR(intHideCheck)` is because without it  you are gluing an Return of some other type to a String.  If it returns something NOT a string, you must convert that to String to add it to a string.  If it IS Null or returns Null you will still get a NRE

Comment: @Matt Wilko, it is a datareader.  I have edited the question.

Comment: @Tim, I amended the question after Matt Wilko posted.

Comment: An exception is thrown when I add the cast i.e. cstr(objDBDR(intHideCheck)).

Comment: Setting Option Strict On or Off will not influence what happens at runtime. It is a compiler directive.

Comment: if it is nothing you cant convert it to string

Comment: are you missing a property ref?  just before that, you have `objDBDR.GetName()` the problem ref though seems to be trying to glue the object itself to the string; like maybe `objDBDR.GetValue()`

Comment: @Plutonix, The problem is that with Option Strict set to on I have to cast the Object objDBDR(intHideCheck).  If I cast it to a string then I get an error.  If I leave OPTION STRICT OFF and do not cast it then it works.

Answer (score 0):

**When you have OPTION STRICT OFF:**
On runtime your object `objDBDR(intHideCheck)` will be automatically converted(if it possible) to type string.
From MSDN

> For strings in Visual Basic, the empty string equals Nothing

`objDBDR(intHideCheck)` return `Nothing` which will be converted to string as empty string.

**When you have OPTION STRICT ON:**
This option restrict implicit conversions, and you must convert objects to string by your self.
For function `Cstr` if parameter is `null`, then runtime error will be throw

This answer will explain why runtime error will be thrown:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/979911/1565525